# Combine two lists when creating dataframe R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following situtation with two `list`: `Path` and `UTMZones`

```
> Path
[[1]]
[1] "/home/rus/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190824T003615_20190824T003640_028704_033FD2_7CC8.SAFE/"

[[2]]
[1] "/home/rus/S2A_MSIL2A_20190827T105621_N0213_R094_T30TVK_20190827T141656.SAFE/"

[[3]]
[1] "/home/rus/S2B_MSIL2A_20190826T153819_N0213_R011_T18TXL_20190826T195901.SAFE/"
```

The second list (the Null is okay)

```
> UTMZones
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "30"

[[3]]
[1] "18"
```

Using this as input I am creating a `df` with the following code:

```
df<-enframe(Path, name = "number", value = "uri") %>%
        unnest %>%
        mutate(plugin = case_when(substr(uri, 11, 12) == "S1" ~ "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", TRUE ~ "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM18N_ReaderPlugIn"))
```

The code works but now I need to insert a small modification. In the last part of the code, when creating the dataframe I am doing

```
 ~ paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", UTMZones, "N_ReaderPlugIn", collapse = "")))
```

This code of course does not work. What I am trying to do is that when creating the `df`, for position `[i]` in `Path`, the first position of `UTMZones` (e.g. `[j]` should be used in the `paste` function

I have been trying with a two-variable `for` loop but I do not get the right result:

```
for (i in seq_along(Path)){
      for(j in seq_along(UTMZones)){

        df<-enframe(Path[[i]], name = "number", value = "uri") %>%
        unnest %>%
        mutate(plugin = case_when(substr(uri, 11, 12) == "S1" ~ "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", TRUE ~ paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", UTMZones[[j]], "N_ReaderPlugIn", collapse = "")))

      }
    }
```

-- EDIT --

The output should look like this. Note how the **UTM** changes in sequence using `UTMZones` as reference.

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  number uri                                                                     plugin                                                                      
   <int> <chr>                                                                   <chr>                                                                       
1      1 /home/rus/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190824T003615_20190824T003640_028704_033F? class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn               
2      2 /home/rus/S2A_MSIL2A_20190827T105621_N0213_R094_T30TVK_20190827T141656? class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM30...
3      3 /home/rus/S2B_MSIL2A_20190826T153819_N0213_R011_T18TXL_20190826T195901? class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM18...
```

-- EDIT 2 --

This is the run of the code with @Ronak Shah solution

```
>     UTMZones[lengths(UTMZones) == 0] <- ""
> library(tidyverse)
> df<-enframe(Path, name = "number", value = "uri") %>%
+       mutate(UTM  = UTMZones) %>%
+       unnest %>%  
+       mutate(plugin = ifelse(substr(uri, 11, 12) == "S1", 
+                              "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", 
+                              paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", 
+                                     UTM, "N_ReaderPlugIn", collapse = "")))
> df$plugin[[3]]
[1] "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTMN_ReaderPlugInclass org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM30N_ReaderPlugInclass org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM18N_ReaderPlugIn"
```

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: @RonakShah I have edited the question to show what the output should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in `base R`

```
UTMZones <- lapply(UTMZones, function(x) replace(x, is.null(x), ""))
within(stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))[2:1],{ UTM <- unlist(UTMZones);plugin <- ifelse(substr(values, 11, 12) == "S1", 
 "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", 
    paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", 
         UTM, "N_ReaderPlugIn"))})
```

If we don't need the 'UTM' column

```
transform(stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))[2:1], 
    plugin= ifelse(substr(values, 11, 12) == "S1", 
 "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", 
    paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", 
         unlist(UTMZones), "N_ReaderPlugIn")))
```

Comment: seems to work. Only to note that inside the `paste0` should be `UTMZones` and not `UTM` the variable used. Also, as with the solution of @Ronak, an extra column UTM is created. That is fine, I can just deleted but I am wondering where in your code this column is being created

Comment: @GCGM Actually, we don't need the `UTM` column` in the `ifelse`, you can directly use `unlist(UTMZones)` insstead of creating the column

Comment: Just for clarification, what is the `[2:1]` doing at the begining of the code?

Comment: @GCGM  It is just that the columns are reordered with 'ind' column as first  For example `stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))` output and `stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))[2:1]`  By default, the `stack` returns the 'values' column as first column

Comment: Nice trick thanks! I like the fact of having the solution with `base`

Comment: By the way, I see here the columns in the datafram are called `ind` `values` and `plugin`. I could rename them afterwards but is it possible when createing the dataframe to set their names to `number` `uri` and `pluging`

Comment: @GCGM Yes, you can use `setNames(stack(...)[2:1], c("number", "uri"))`

Comment: I am getting unexpected `)` ... not sure how to proceed

Comment: @GCGM  I meant `setNames(stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))[2:1], c("number", "url"))`  May be you have an extra `)` added at the eend

Comment: could you add it to the code in the answer. I have been trying to add the `c("number", "url"))` part in different ways, checking the closing `)` carrefully and I get different sort of errors

Answer (score 1):

Few changes in the code. First replace the `NULL` elements to blank elements

```
UTMZones[lengths(UTMZones) == 0] <- ""
```

then include `UTMZones` in the dataframe so that it is easy to replace values.

```
library(tidyverse)

enframe(Path, name = "number", value = "uri") %>%
    mutate(UTM  = UTMZones) %>%
    unnest %>%  
    mutate(plugin = ifelse(substr(uri, 11, 12) == "S1", 
    "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", 
paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", 
            UTM, "N_ReaderPlugIn")))
```

Comment: I see, I was trying to create `for` loops or iterate using `lapply` but this is more straigh forward. The only thing is that your code is adding a forth column called UTM in the `dataframe`.

Comment: @GCGM So if not needed add `%>%
  select(-UTM)` in the end?

Comment: I have edited the question to add something that is not working with your code

Comment: @GCGM I am not sure if I understand your edit. If I store the result from above in `df`. For me `df$plugin[2]` returns
`[1] "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM30N_ReaderPlugIn"` and `df$plugin[3]` `[1] "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM18N_ReaderPlugIn"`

Comment: strange, I double checked and I stil get that.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but it seems to work for me as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: I have posted the output of running your code to see if we find where is the issue

Answer (score 1):

Although @akrun and @Ronak Shah answers are much more efficient and definitely this is what I am looking for, I'll put down my - not perfect - attempt which is much more basic but I would say easy to follow in case someone is interested.

Since I was not managing to itereate in the dataframe properly, once having the dataframe created with a wrong content for the `plugin` column, I used the following code to correct it.

```
for (i in seq_along(Path)){
      if (substr(Path[[i]], 11,12) == 'S1') {
        df$plugin[[i]] <- 'class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn'
      } else {
        df$plugin[[i]] <- paste0("class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM", UTMZones[[i]], "N_ReaderPlugIn", collapse = "")
      }
    }
```